# JSON.stringfy return data different compared with the object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some code:

```
console.log("444444: ", profile, JSON.stringify(profile))
```

when I check the log:

[image: log]

Basically I want to know why I can not see

value: [0]

and i want to pass this profile object to backend and looks like backend is not getting this value field.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, but it looks like value is an array containing the number 0?

Comment: @wooooooo yes, value is an array containing 0, i wonder why it does not show up when I  log the object, however when I do JSON.stringfy, I am able to find this value. 
Also, when I pass this object to next function, looks like it does not contain this value [0]

Comment: In the console log in your screenshot, it does show up. `Array(1)` means it is an array with a length of 1, which is the `[0]` you see stringified. Make sure you log it immediately before passing it to the next function, and then check how that function accesses the object.

Comment: The data is not different, but browsers just show *less* output when you console.log to reduce clutter. Specifically they only nest a few levels deep before they start summarizing. The `JSON.stringify()` version is what really gets sent if you json-encode it, so if you're missing something in the backend the issue has nothing to do with how `console.log()` shows things.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you remove `profile.value` somewhere after you outputted it to `console.log()`. Try looking for `delete profile.value;` or `profile.value = undefined;`.

Comment: as you can see in my code, i console log 
profile and JSON.string(profile) at the same time.

from the result, I can see value: [0] in json output, but not the profile object output. I did not delete it anywhere, at least from this line of console.log

Comment: @ilikechocolate This answer is correct, the object is logged to the console with the property, but by the time you click the drop down it is gone. I am able to reproduce this behaviour by adding `delete profile.value` after the `console.log`.

Comment: @ilikechocolate This stems from the fact that your browser lazy loads the properties. You can see the difference between lazy loading and pre-loading here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pymdqv?file=src/app/app.component.ts. Stackblitz loads the properties at the time of logging, while firefox loads them when you click the dropdown.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton thanks for your information.Weird part is, if I change the value from [0] to [1], then I am able to see the value [1].

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse the data first and then stringify

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(profile))
```